# Java Regular expression pattern match positive lookahead

Tags: java, regex

I've create a regular expression to match

- user_ent_mov
- user_ent_mov_123
- user_mov_ent123

But it shouldn't match

- user_ent
- user_ent123
- user_mov123

My Regual Expression

```
^user_(?:ent(?=_mov)|mov(?=_ent)).*$
```

Everything is working fine. But when I run exhaustive tests my regx fails.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I've pre-compiled my regex and its not declared static.

Comment: Regex seems fine.. for what input is it failing?

Comment: @Pradeep could you post any error message you received during such a crash?

Comment: My bad.. it conflicting with another regex match I've constructed to match only the text like: user_ent :).... It's working I could have little longer to test :)

Comment: @Pradeep If it was misunderstanding then consider removing your question.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple.

```
user_(ent_mov|mov_ent)_?\d*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sG2lF0/1)

use `String#matches()` to check for matches.

```
String regex="user_(ent_mov|mov_ent)_?\\d*";

System.out.println("user_ent_mov".matches(regex));    //true
System.out.println("user_ent_mov_123".matches(regex));//true
System.out.println("user_mov_ent123".matches(regex)); //true
System.out.println("user_ent".matches(regex));        //false
System.out.println("user_ent123".matches(regex));     //false
System.out.println("user_mov123".matches(regex));     //false
```

Comment: Nice compact solution, +1 :)

Comment: How could I miss this ? Thanks for reminding the basics +1 :)

Comment: regex should be as simple as it is to make it more faster.